# How to delete duplicate indexes

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm looking for a script removing duplicate indexes automatically instead of checking and deleting manually one by one table.

Is it possible to delete through SQL code or PL/pgSQL code?

The script is using finding duplicate indexes:

```
SELECT
    indrelid::regclass AS TableName
    ,array_agg(indexrelid::regclass) AS Indexes
FROM pg_index 
GROUP BY 
    indrelid
    ,indkey 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Automating dropping database objects is basically a bad idea. Those objects exists, or did at some time, for a purpose.  For each object you want to drop you need to ask: Is that purpose still valid or not. If it is then do you have an alternative solution? Your proposal seems to fall into the category of "I want to change the database, but I don't want to take the time to understand it". Look and consider the warning @jjanes gives. It will do what you are requesting, but will it do what you want. They are quite likely to be very different things.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it seems unwise.

In `psql` you can use \gexec to run arbitrary SQL queries/statements which are composed as the results of another query.  In pl/pgsql you can use [dynamic queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to execute whatever statements you want composed from the results of other queries.

But your query will identify different indexes as being duplicates.  For example, a btree index and a gin_trgm_ops index on the same column are not really duplicates as they support different operations, and blindly dropping one would probably be a mistake.  Also, indkey contains 0 for any expressions, so it would identify expressional indexes over different expressions as being identical.

So while you could do this in `psql` to drop all but the first occurence in your array of duplicates, you really probably should not:

```
select 'drop index '||unnest(indexes[2:]) from (SELECT
    indrelid::regclass AS TableName
    ,array_agg(indexrelid::regclass) AS Indexes
FROM pg_index 
GROUP BY 
    indrelid
    ,indkey 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) foo \gexec
```

You could refine it by grouping by the definition of the index, after stripping off the name of the index with a regexp, to exclude grouping together index that are not really duplicates.

```
SELECT              
    indrelid::regclass AS TableName
    ,array_agg(indexrelid::regclass) AS Indexes
FROM pg_index 
GROUP BY 
    indrelid
    ,indkey 
    ,regexp_replace(pg_get_indexdef(pg_index.indexrelid),'^CREATE (UNIQUE )?INDEX (\w+|".+")','')  
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

I don't guarantee the regexp is safe against all maliciously crafted index names.  It also lumps unique and non-unique index together--presumably you actually want to lump them together but then ensure that one of the unique ones is the one that survives.  To be complete, you probably also want to do something with indisvalid as well.